# in transaction, what is 'hash' data?

Tags: transactions, bitcoind, hash, bitcoin-core-development

i'm studying `Bitcoin: A Peer-to-Peer Electronic Cash System Satoshi Nakamoto`

and this paper introduce a transaction model. (above picture)
[image]

but i don't understand what is 'Hash' means exactly

i think Hash is same  `Bitcoin API JSON-RPC - signrawtransaction` function

it means hash(txid + owner's public key)? then what method used hash function?

or  hash(result of `signrawtransaction` + RIPEMD160(sha256(pub k)) )? then what method used to hash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hash refers to the signature hash, to which all tx data except for the input script is committed to (unless you are signing with a sighash flag other than ALL).

The signature hash is what is signed with ECDSA to produce the signature.

Comment: This might help: https://teachbitcoin.io/presentations/transaction_build.html#/5

Comment: thanks. but i have one more question. in the picture of center(1 and 2's transaction), why `Hash(Owner 2's pub K + signature hash)` is Owner 1's Signature?       Assuming the signature of 1 is correct, why 1's Sign arrow not heads Hash, point out 1's Signature?

Comment: Thats because the transaction output is intended for owner 2. His pubkey is commited to the 2nd transaction. Specifically it is inthe output of tx2. He has the private key 2 that can spend it.

Comment: Its the original paper, but the illustration isn’t the most intuitive depiction.